# Java PrintService breaking words beyond page width

Tags: java, printing

I am using below function to print document in java:

```
public static String printDocument(String textToPrint,PrintService mPrinter, PrintService defaultPrintService) {
        String returnText = "";
        try{
            DocPrintJob job = defaultPrintService.createPrintJob();
            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(textToPrint.getBytes());
            Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(is, DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE, null);

            PrintJobWatcher pjDone = new PrintJobWatcher(job);

            job.print(doc, null);

            pjDone.waitForDone();

            is.close();
            returnText = "Printed successfully!";
        }catch (Exception e){
            returnText="Failed to print because of: "+e.getMessage();
        }

        return returnText;
    }
```

But the problem is that it breaks the long words once line end is reached there by making it difficult to read.
For example for string below:

`textToPrint="Peter Parker Picked A Pack Of Pepper"`

It prints it like this:

`Peter Parker Picked A Pa
ck Of Pepper`

I would want it to simply print the word to next line if it overflows page width:

`Peter Parker Picked A
Pack Of Pepper`

How do I do it?